# Does Kafka Streams also wipes out state store data on internal exceptions?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

I know that state stores are cleared on user exceptions and gets restored from the changelog topic when EOS is enabled. Does this also apply on other internal exceptions that are handled by kafka streams? Like ProducerFencedException or when kafka can't produce the record because the payload is too big or on any connection related excpetions? If not, is it enough to wrap user code with try-catch to prevent time consuming restorations?

I could not reproduce an internal exception, but i did throw an user defined exception in the topology and i  saw the store was cleared and also restored from the changelog topic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using a `try-catch` around your code should be enough; the exceptions won't get bubbled up until Kafka Streams needs to handle it.  It's always a great practice to do this with your processors in Kafka Streams, regardless of EOS being enabled.

Comment: So you mean by "yes" that state is wiped also on internal kafka exceptions? Because i cannot catch those.

Comment: Internal kafka exception are two type: on-consume/deserialize or on produce, and with kafka-stream you could use default handlers or implement your owns. Please check those configs _ default.deserialization.exception.handler _ default.production.exception.handle